# Why .NET will does not support SSE in 32bit (while ryujit 64bit can) while Mono supports both 32bit and 64bit?

Tags: .net, mono, ryujit

Ryujit will will support SSE instructions, however Ryujit is only for 64bit.

Most of customer stick to Windows 32 bit OS because of company policy and budget (due to testing cost).

My understanding is Ryujit is new "JIT scheme optimized for 64bit".

However, as you know, SSE instructions set exits on 32 bit and 64 bit.

Mono.Simd works  x86 or Arm 32 bit processor.

(Java SIMD call seems to work on x86 and 64bit).

Our project is for any CPU, so it is very difficult for me to tell customer that "Please use Mono, because they have SSE support, or change CPU and OS."

Why MS .NET Framework for x86 does not provide with SSE command support while Ryujit can?

(I am not CPU specialist, but I hope if .NET have an options to choose "force SSE on this command(if possible)")

Comment: It's pretty simple, the old JIT is old and legacy... Mono and RyuJIT are new and support more.

Comment: Many mobile laptop are still shipped with 32 bit os and 32bit .net (includig mine). The word "Legacy" should be used for a old product, such as "IE6", "Clipart",or "Vista". I don't think microsoft will drop 32 bit os release for next 20 years.

Comment: There's a difference between "drop" and "maintain".  They are maintaining the 32 bit compiler, and not doing new development for it. It's like when they released Windows 7, they still "supported" XP for a while, but they didn't develop new features for it.  Most mobile devices these days have 64 bit CPU's, and it probably won't be long before MS officially declares 32 bit dead (maybe another 2 or 3 years at most).

Comment: Mono simd is just a few intrinsics its imho pretty poor  , along with the JIT. Bench mark it in a idealistic app eg generics /interface and compare. Its a great library ,average run time and a long way behind the java ones.   1.3 gig memory on 32 bit  CLR is a serious issue for decent apps,.

Answer (score 3):

> RyuJIT is based off of the same codebase as the x86 JIT. While it’s only for x64 right now, it’s a modern compiler that will be the basis of all our JIT compilers in the future: x86, ARM, MDIL and whatever else comes along. Having a single codebase means that .NET programs are more consistent between architectures—put another way, you generally get bug-for-bug compatibility. But having a single codebase also means we can innovate faster and bring you more code generation features more quickly.

- [RyuJIT: The next-generation JIT compiler for .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/09/30/ryujit-the-next-generation-jit-compiler-for-net/)

Basically they built four separate implementations of the JIT compiler, for x86, x64, Itanium and ARM. Itanium is basically dead but that still gives them three implementations to maintain which have very little in common.

I believe the intent is to replace the .NET Framework JIT with RyuJIT once it's sufficiently stable. Indeed the .NET Framework 4.6 includes RyuJIT as the x64 compiler.

Comment: I agree. RyuJit SIMD seems to be a better choice rather than MONO.SIMD. I hope .NET Foundation announce the direction where the developers(or they) will go along in the future.

Comment: "Will RyuJIT replace JIT32 and JIT64 codebases? What about x86 and ARM architectures?

Yes, RyuJIT is our new JIT compiler codebase going forward.  We’re focused on getting a first architecture complete, which is X64. After that, we’ll need to talk with customers, including internal ones, to determine the order of the other architectures. We know that x86 is high on everyone’s lists."

Comment: I'm wondering the exact same thing: certain programs (most?) need to be platform-independent and work for either x86 or x64. The statement above suggests that RyuJIT will eventually be applied for all platforms once it is stable enough; which seems like a logical step. Any updates on this?

Comment: You can now browse the CoreCLR repository https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr where .NET Core is being developed. The issues lists indicate that RyuJIT/x86/Windows is being developed mostly by Microsoft staffers https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6927, while non-MS developers are working on RyuJIT/ARM32/Linux https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/3977.

Answer (score 2):

By thinking about it, for me the reason are:

A) Ryujit is a new JIT compiler, built from scratch, so it can do new and wonderful things. They probably restricted it to 64 bits to make it easier to build it, and because the "current" JIT on 64 bits sometimes was slower than the 32 bits version, so it was "more necessary" on 64 bits

B) Being new and shiny, it is easier to include new functions/extension points (SIMD functions for example)

C) Microsoft doesn't seem want to thinker too with the "old" .NET compiler (I don't consider what they did in .NET 4.5, where they moved some work to a background thread, to be "thinker too much"). If you look closely, you'll see they haven't ever added new OpCodes to the CIL (Common Intermediate Language), the assembly language of .NET (they did changes to the GC and to the .NET libraries, but these are different "things"), and clearly to add SIMD functions they would need to do changes

D) The Mono JIT is "newer" than the .NET JIT "current" compiler (because Mono was "born" later). This can justify why it does support SIMD.

Comment: It may be
1) .NET 32 bit may be  too old for MS to implemenet SSE support .
   (there are many laptops still uses 32 bit OS, including mine...)
2) Microsoft .NET ordinally designed to bind early bind to methods.
However, .NET also moving toward to support Java-like method late-bindings in 64-bit or 128 bit.
At this point, i can say "if you want 32bit SIMD support, use  Mono. Otherwise, please upgrade CPU and OS to 64 bits to use RyuJit's offical SSE.".
For 32 bit, It seems to be Mono.SIMD may be  better choice as long as the entire GUI component is based upon Mono library.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of .Net Core 2.0, RyuJit is now the used jit for x86 code generation, and so enables x86 to take advantage of SSE2 for general floating point and SSE2/AVX2 SIMD instructions for Vector.

In the about-to-be released .Net Core 2.1 you can find a preview of hardware intrinsics that provide access to (nearly) the full range of new instructions on both x86 and x64 CPUs.

At the present time it seems unlikely that we will change .Net Framework over to using RyuJit for x86 code generation.